# XULRunner error in Eclipse / SWT

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, xulrunner

I'm trying to run the **Enhanced JavaScript Bridge** example found [here](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2009/06/16/eclipse-galileo-feature-top-10-list-number-9/).

I created a new project, and added a reference to SWT via:

Project(right-click)-->Properties-->Libraries-->Add Variable-->Configure Variable-->New

However I cannot get this project to run. The error I get depends on what SWT library I'm referencing:

- `org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64_3.103.2.v20150203-1351.jar`: Error is

> Could not instantiate Browser:
>   org.eclipse.swt.internal.mozilla.init.XPCOMInit.GREVersionRange_sizeof()I

- `swt-3.6.1-win32-win32-x86_64\swt.jar`: Error is

> Could not instantiate Browser: No more handles [Could not detect
>   registered XULRunner to use]

It seems I am having a problem with XULRunner or the Mozilla browser. I tried using different XULRunner versions (10, 18, 24) by running `xulrunner.exe --register-global` in the console in their respective folders. It didn't help. I don't know what else to do.

My system is:

- Windows 7 64-bit
- Eclipse Luna 4.4.2

Comment: I've been investigating this during the last 3 hours and I think it can be related with us using Firefox in 32-bit, but I don't know for sure. @sangil, did you manage to get it working? It is important for me.

Comment: @Chexpir - see below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I managed to get XULRunner working in the following way:

**1) Download XULrunner 24.0. You can find the versions I used here:**

- 64-bit: https://osdn.net/projects/sfnet_runawfe/downloads/SRC%20and%20BIN%20files/extras/xulrunner-1.9.2.25-win64.zip/
- 32-bit: http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/xulrunner/releases/24.0b10/runtimes/xulrunner-24.0b10.en-US.win32.zip

**2) In my Java code I create a Composite to contain my Browser object.**

In its constructor I set the path to the xulrunner folder I downloaded in step 1, and then instantiate the browser:

```
public class MyBrowserComp extends Composite {

    private String pathToXulrunner = "C:\\path\\to\\xulrunner";`

    private Browser browser;

    public MyBrowserComp(..) {
        System.setProperty("org.eclipse.swt.browser.XULRunnerPath", pathToXulrunner);
        browser = new Browser(this, SWT.MOZILLA);
    }
}
```

Comment: 64-bit link gives a 403

Comment: 64-bit link fixed

Comment: The 64-bit link is now XULRunner for 64-bit Linux, not 64-bit Windows. Is this answer still valid?

Comment: You're right. I placed a new link to Windows 64-bit version.